# CSS: Truncat text with 'ellipsis' and overflow 'hidden' in bootstrap tab-names

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ellipsis

How can i use the ellipse function in bootstrap-tabs?

You can check the problem directly on my website, so its better to see my problem i think:

> **Profile with 6 Tabs**:
>   http://chris.lunatics-carclub.at/profil_stackoverflow/9
>
> **Profile with 3 Tabs**:
>   http://chris.lunatics-carclub.at/profil_stackoverflow/1

- Please notice: It's a test-website(homeserver)

> The problem appears, if you resize the viewport in the browser:
>   [image]

6 tabs should be the maximum amount, normal i need 2 to 3 tabs.
But, if someone has more "cars"(=tabs) then normal, it should be displayed correct too.

If i truncate the string via PHP, i cannot make it responsive, so i hope there is a way to do it via CSS.

> CSS

```
.o_ellipsis {   
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;        
}
```

> HTML

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
<li class="active o_ellipsis"><a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> {name}</a></li>
<li class="o_ellipsis"><a href="#tab_car_1" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-car"></i> {name2}</a></li>
<li class="o_ellipsis"><a href="#tab_car_2" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-car"></i> {name3}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You need to put a max-width to work. Otherwise, the best solution here is show all tabs that fits, and hide in a menu the next tabs. It's a common practice and users known it.

Comment: It would wonder me, if we become another member which owns more then 5 Cars. 

So, its not neccecary to make this "function" for 1, or maybe 2 users the next years.

Can i set the max-width responsive, or is there any built-in bootstrap-version? 

I've tried max-width:100%, and other things but it doesnt work.

Comment: No, the max-width to 100% said to browser that the size is the 100% of the tab, or that's the same that text fits in entire tab. You need to put `max-width: 10em` for example to limit the space to the text. You can do more responsive if the width of the tab has a percent value. For example, if the tab sizes are max 18% width you can put 5 tabs and you have space to a extra button to the menu. With this, ellipsis must work because tab doesn't expands.